# Error Converting Varchar to Numeric Syntax

Tags: sql, syntax, syntax-error, varchar

I'm trying to build code that will generate a file in a specific format. The code worked in its entirety until I added A.PrevYTDSales and A.YtdQtySold, so I'm not sure what's going on. It now gives me an error saying "error converting varchar to numeric" so I'm assuming I have a syntax error somewhere but I can't find where. Below is the code.

```
select 
    Inv.StockCode                                                           -- part
    + '|' + Inv.Description                                                 -- desc
    + '|' +      isnull(
            replace(
                            CONVERT(varchar, 
                    CAST(
                        isnull(
                            case when 0 > (Inv.QOH - isnull(Sor.QOO,0)) then 0
                            else (Inv.QOH - isnull(Sor.QOO,0)) end
                            ,0)
                        as Money) 
                    , 1)
                ,'.00','') 
            ,'0')                                                           -- QOH
    + '|' + replace(convert(varchar,cast(BoxQty as money),1),'.00','')      -- box qty
    + '|' + YTDSales                                                        -- YTD Qty Sold
    + '|' + PrevYTDSales                                                    -- Prev YTD Qty Sold
    + '|' + convert(varchar,TRY_CAST(Mass as NUMERIC(19,4)))                -- mass
    + '|' + isnull(convert(varchar,DueDt+3,101),' ')                        -- duedt
    + '|' + 
    case when isnull(convert(varchar,DueDt+3,101),' ') = ' ' then ' ' 
         when 0 > (Inv.QOH - isnull(Sor.QOO,0)) then
            isnull(
        replace(
            CONVERT(varchar, 
                CAST(
                    isnull(
                        case when 0 > (GitQty - isnull(Sor.QOOtoPOS,0)) then 0
                        else (GitQty - isnull(Sor.QOOtoPOS,0)) end
                        ,0)
                    as Money) 
                , 1)
            ,'.00','') 
        ,'0') 
        else
           replace(convert(varchar,convert(money,GitQty),1),'.00','')
        end                                                                 -- QTY coming
    + '|' + COO                                                             -- COO
    + '|' + Tariff                                                          -- tariff
    + '|' + Location                                                        -- Customer
    + '|' + isnull(Cus.Customer,' ')                                        -- customer
    + '|' + isnull(
                    replace(
                        replace(
                            Cus.CustStockCode
                            ,Char(13),'')
                        ,Char(10),'')
                    ,' ')                                                        customer part          
    + '|' + isnull(Cus.StockCode,' ')                                       
    + '|' + 'R' 
            as partlist
    from (
        select
        A.StockCode         as StockCode
        ,B.Description      as Description
        ,Sum(QtyOnHand)     as QOH
        ,B.UserField2       as BoxQty
        ,A.YtdQtySold       as YTDSales 
        ,A.PrevYearQtySold  as PrevYTDSales
        ,B.Mass             as Mass
        ,B.ProductClass
        ,B.CountryOfOrigin  as COO              
        ,B.TariffCode       as Tariff           
        ,case
            when Warehouse = '01' then 'All W/H'
            when Warehouse = '02' then 'All W/H'
            else ''
        end                 as Location         
        from CompanyR.dbo.InvWarehouse A
        left join CompanyR.dbo.InvMaster B on A.StockCode = B.StockCode 
        left join CompanyR.dbo.[InvMaster+] C on B.StockCode = C.StockCode
        where Warehouse in ('01', '02')
        and A.StockCode not like 'TEC%'
        and B.StockCode is not null
        group by A.StockCode , B.Description, B.UserField2, A.YtdQtySold, A.PrevYearQtySold, Mass, B.ProductClass
        ,B.CountryOfOrigin      
        ,B.TariffCode                   
        ,case
            when Warehouse = '01' then 'All W/H'
            when Warehouse = '02' then 'All W/H'
            else ''
        end                             
        ) Inv
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
        select
        sum(case 
            when (Getdate()+57) < MLineShipDate then 0 
            else (MOrderQty)
            end
            )           as QOO,
        sum(case 
            when ( MLineShipDate > isnull(DueDt,  GetDate() ) )
                 AND
                 ( MLineShipDate < isnull(POSDt,  GetDate()+57) ) 
                  then  MOrderQty
            else 0
            end
            )           as QOOtoPOS,
        DueDt,
        GitQty,
        POSDt,
        A.MStockCode        as StockCode
        from CompanyR.dbo.SorDetail A
        left join CompanyR.dbo.SorMaster B on A.SalesOrder = B.SalesOrder
        left join (
            select  StockCode
            ,(ExpectedDueDate) as DueDt 
            ,SUM(GtrQuantity-QtyReceived) as GitQty
            from CompanyR.dbo.GtrDetail A
            where TransferComplete  <> 'Y'
            and CompanyR.dbo.get_week(ExpectedDueDate,0) >=  CompanyR.dbo.get_week(GETDATE(),0) 
            and ExpectedDueDate = (select Min(ExpectedDueDate) 
                                    from CompanyR.dbo.GtrDetail B where TransferComplete  <> 'Y' and A.StockCode = B.StockCode
                                    and CompanyR.dbo.get_week(ExpectedDueDate,0) >=  CompanyR.dbo.get_week(GETDATE(),0) ) 
            group by StockCode, ExpectedDueDate
        ) GIT on A.MStockCode = GIT.StockCode
        left join (
            select
            MStockCode 
            ,min(MLatestDueDate)    as POSDt
            from CompanyR.dbo.PorMasterDetail
            where MCompleteFlag <> 'Y'
            and MLatestDueDate > getdate()
            and MStockCode not like '-%'
            and MStockCode not like '#%'
            and MStockCode not like '*%'
            group by MStockCode
        ) POS on A.MStockCode = POS.MStockCode

        where 1=1
        and A.MLineShipDate < dateadd(week,8,getdate())
        and A.MLineShipDate >= DATEADD(s, -0,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
        and A.MStockCode not like '*%'
        and A.MStockCode not like '-%'
        and B.OrderStatus not in ('\','*','9') 
        group by A.MStockCode,DueDt,POSDt,GitQty
        ) Sor on Inv.StockCode = Sor.StockCode

        LEFT JOIN CompanyR.dbo.ArCustStkXref Cus on Inv.StockCode = Cus.StockCode and Cus.Customer <> ''
```

It's supposed to output something like this

```
    098-01-PK|#6 , 3MM DL WASHER 200 PAIR PK|0|0|1.0000| | |TWN|7318.22.0000|All W/H| | | |L
098-01-PK|#6 , 3MM DL WASHER 200 PAIR PK|0|0|1.0000| | |TWN|7318.22.0000|| | | |L
098-01|#6 , 3MM DL WASHER PAIR|0|3,000|1.0000| | |TWN|7318.22.0000|All W/H| | | |L
098-01|#6 , 3MM DL WASHER PAIR|0|3,000|1.0000| | |TWN|7318.22.0000|| | | |L
```

Anyone have any ideas where I could be having an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only conversion to numeric that you have is for the `Mass`, column.

Since you added the new columns into the group by, probably new rows would appear showing the `Mass` column with (maybe) a null or some new strange value.

Try running the query from the query inside the `from` clause by itself and then looking for distinct values for the `Mass` column and check if they all are numeric.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Strange, none of the columns seem to have issues when they generate when I go into the FROM clause. The values are also what i'd expect to see.